# Bisection Method Implementation

Tags: c, debugging

I'm working on a program to program the bisection method:
https://www.calculushowto.com/bisection-method/

I know there's questions similar to this one but I want to see if my own one works.

```
double func(double x) {
    return x * x - 3 * x - 1;
}
    
double bisect(double (*f)(double), double a, double b, double e) {
    double mid = (a + b) / 2;
    while (abs(mid) > e) {
        if (f(mid) < 0) {
            mid = a;
        } else {
            mid = b;
        }
    }
      
    return mid;       
}
```

`func()` is the function I'm using to test the bisection method. In the other function, `a` is the left point, `b` is the right point and `e` is the error bound.

Any mistakes that I didn't catch?

Comment: Is there something you think is wrong? Or you are just looking for a code review? (if the latter, maybe try on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It may look like bisection at first sight, but I very much doubt it is. And that's not how the error bound works either. [Use a debugger to step through the program and understand what is going on and compare that with your expectations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the posted implementation, many of them could be easily addressed if the function were *tested* in a complete program.

- The *midpoint* is calculated only *once*, at the beginning. Unless this was meant to be a recursive function, it should be updated inside the loop. To be nitpicking, the evaluation itself could be done differently, by first calculating a `width = right - left` and then `mid = left + width / 2.0`.
- The termination condition is wrong, it should compare the *width* of the current interval with the limit or even the absolute value of `f(mid)` with a chosen minimal bound, not the value of `mid`.
- Inside the loop, the value of `mid` is changed according to the signness of `f(mid)`, but it should be the opposite: either the left bound or the right bound should be assigned to the value `mid`. The assumption that the function is ascending should be also somehow documented.
- The function returns `mid` unconditionally, but either `abs(f(a))` or `abs(f(b))` could be less than `abs(f(mid))`.